# Javascript - Loop within an array

Tags: javascript

I know this is going to be an easy one, and I have tried stitching together different pieces of the puzzle from stack overflow, but there is some part of my brain that's just not working.

I am writing a web collect JavaScript where it should parse my cart details via the data layer.

```
var cartcontent = [{
"item": tealiumStaticImpressions.cart.product_sku.toString().split(".", 2)[0] + '.' + tealiumStaticImpressions.cart.product_sku.toString().split(".", 2)[1],
"quantity": parseInt(tealiumStaticImpressions.cart.product_quantity),
"price": parseFloat(tealiumStaticImpressions.cart.cart_product_price)
}];
```

I need "item" "quantity" and "price" to apply to all items  - it currently picks up only the first.

I have found this as a partial match

```
for (var key in p.cart_product_sku) {
    if (p.cart_product_sku.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log("item" + " -> " + p.cart_product_sku[key]);
    }
}
```

below is expected result

```
 {item: 'item_1', price: 19.9, quantity: 1},
 {item: 'item_2', price: 29.7, quantity: 3}
```

But am unsure how it all works together

**EDIT**
Here is the contents of tealiumStaticImpressions

```js
tealiumStaticImpressions.cart {
    cart_product_id: Array(2),
    cart_product_price: Array(2),
    cart_product_quantity: Array(2),
    cart_product_sku: Array(2),
    cart_total_items: "2",
     …
}
cart_product_id: Array(2) 0: "J181LS81.NVY.10"
1: "J173SS202.MUS.3"
length: 2 __proto__: Array(0) cart_product_price: Array(2) 
0: "81.81"
1: "72.72"
length: 2 __proto__: Array(0) cart_product_quantity: Array(2) 
0: "1"
1: "1"
length: 2 __proto__: Array(0) cart_product_sku: Array(2) 
0: "J181LS81.NVY.10"
1: "J173SS202.MUS.3"
length: 2 __proto__: Array(0) cart_total_items: "2"
cart_total_value: "169.98"
checkout_step: "1"
ecommerce_action: "checkout"
page_type: "cart"
product_category: (2) ["Long Sleeve Shirts", "Short Sleeve Shirts"] product_name: (2) ["DONOVAN CHECK SHIRT", "HENRI LINEN CHECK SHIRT"] product_price: (2) ["89.99", "79.99"] product_quantity: (2) ["1", "1"] product_size: (2) ["LT", "4XL"] product_sku: (2) ["J181LS81.NVY.10", "J173SS202.MUS.3"] product_subcategory: (2) ["Shirts", "Shirts"] __proto__: Object
```

Comment: Why don't you dump the contents of tealiumStaticImpressions in the DevTools and post it here. Knowing the structure is necessary to answer your question. Also, consider sharing where this data is coming from and using additional tags to attract users that have worked with the platform you're working with.

Comment: Sorry. of course that would be a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, I think it's as easy as you supposed. The basic assumptions we make is that,

1. The any iterable property (a property that can be iterated over, like arrays) in `cart` correspond, index for index, to the other iterable properties. That is, `cart_product_id[0]` corresponds to `cart_product_price[0]` and `cart_product_quantity[0]`, etc.
2. The property names of our new collection can come from the name of the `cart` props themselves. So, taking the following props: `cart_product_id`, `cart_product_price`, `cart_product_quantity`, etc, our object would look like:

   ```
   {
     id: 0,
     price: "$0.10",
     quantity: 10
     ... 
   }
   ```

Those assumptions will let us create a loop that first iterates through the total quantity of products we expect, and then trought the properties in  `cart`. The second loop will feed the new collection of items, one item at a time.

```
const cart = tealiumStaticImpressions.cart;
const totalItems = parseInt(cart.cart_total_items);
// Some of the properties in `cart` don't provide item information. We'll exclude them
const exclude = ['cart_total_items']; 

let collection = [];

for (let i =0; i < totalItems; i++) {
  let currentItem = {};

  Object.keys(cart).forEach(key => {  // Loop through only own properties in cart
    if (exclude.some(ex => ex === key)) return; // Don't process keys in cart that are in the exclude list

    let prop = key.split("_").pop(); // Get the word after the last "_"

    currentItem[prop] = cart[key][i]; // Map the value of this property to our new collection item
  });

  // We populated our current item, now push into the collection
  collection.push(currentItem); 
}
```